# Log scale for contour plot in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Is it possible to use a log scale in a contour plot? The plot should look like `contour(log10(data))`, but with correct labelling of the colorbar.

Comment: There's a `scale` keyword to `cgrad` for making log-transformed color scales, if that's what you mean. It's unfortunately broken.

Comment: I believe that's what I mean, yes. That's too bad, it's a feature I use quite often in matplotlib.

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotUtils.jl/issues/33 . Plots is, by necessity, not fully feature complete with an old and mature library as matplotlib. You will notice there are 200 open issues. It's always possible to open another, but the best way to get a functionality that would be useful for you is to implement it and submit a PR.

Comment: That's not even a grumpy remark, but the raw truth :-D

Comment: I am aware of that, and I very much appreciate the very honourable work done by you and so many others, both in the julia community and elsewhere. I try my best to support these efforts wherever I can, but in this particular instance I think I don't have the experience required for contributing a PR.